# Redirect permanent / https://www.mysite.com/ exceptions

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a site that is completely servered through ssl.  I need to allow an external connection on a single page through http though.

Currently in my http.conf I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
..
Redirect permanent / https://www.mysite.com/
..
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to add an exception here for a certain page that I only want servered and **never through a redirect** if possible as http...

```
http://www.mysite.com/directory/page.php
```

I tried adding the following but of course this by itself works just fine but in conjunction with what I have above it creates redirect loops.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
..
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteRule ^/directory/page$ http://www.mysite.com/directory/page.php [R=301,L]
..
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I would check the ordering of the rules. If you have another redirect above it that is trying to make it go to https then you will loop. Step through the logic yourself line by line and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what finally worked:

```
# Force HTTPS for entire site
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\s/directory/page.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Force HTTP for a given page
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/directory/page.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/directory/page$ http://www.mysite.com/directory/page.php [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/directory/page.php  http://www.mysite.com/directory/page.php [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directory/page.php
RewriteRule ^/(.*)  https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: With this if I browse to `http://www.mysite.com/directory/page.php` it takes me to `index.php`, if I browse to `https://www.mysite.com/directory/page.php` it stays a secure connection

Comment: Made a couple edits to support this new requirement on forcing /directory/page.php to be non-ssl. On redirecting to the index, I'm not sure, maybe you have something else in your configuration? I suspect that /directory/page.php is not the real url so maybe you missed changing it somewhere?